# how to iterate json object array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have a `json` array like this:

```
[{  "qbCondition": "OR"},{"fieldId": "ca.Primary_Diagnosis_Dt" ,"operator":"not_equal","fieldValue": "1991/11/17"},{"fieldId": "ca.Clinical_Stage","operator": "not_equal","fieldValue": "I"}]
```

I just want to put this array into this:

```
var rules_widgets = {  condition: 'qbCondition',  rules: [{ id: 'fieldId',operator: 'operator', value: 'fieldValue'},{id: 'fieldValue',operator: 'operator', value: 'fieldValue' },]};
```

I tried this:

```
 $(data).each(function(idx, obj){ 
  $(obj).each(function(key, value){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(key) + ": " + JSON.stringify(value));
            });
        });
```

But I don't know how to put these values dynamically to create above `json`

Can you guys help me? Thanks

Comment: good question! Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't have any idea I don't know from where I can start

Comment: Here https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bE96V5rhHdakvwSmi7GYCg&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=iterate+javascript+object+array

Comment: thanks akshay but i already  got the values but how can i set this values dynamically to create rule_widgets

Comment: you'll have to create multiple objects while iterating over the json you have and push them in rules array and set the values to rules_widgets

Comment: ok thanks let me try  ..

Comment: ok! is that qbcondition in rules_widget condition correct or you meant "OR" to be there?

Comment: Please put your code here! we'll try to help

Comment: i want to put OR there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t4yvn1zu/)

```
var x = [{  "qbCondition": "OR"},{"fieldId": "ca.Primary_Diagnosis_Dt" ,"operator":"not_equal","fieldValue": "1991/11/17"},{"fieldId": "ca.Clinical_Stage","operator": "not_equal","fieldValue": "I"}]

var rules = [];
for(var i=1; i<x.length; i++) {
    rules.push({
    id: x[i].fieldId,
    operator: x[i].operator,
    value: x[i].fieldValue
  })
}

var rules_widgets = {
    condition: x[0].qbCondition,
  rules: rules
}
```

Comment: thanks for ans but this give me output like {"rules":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},

Comment: Did you parse the json before using this?